# Java AWT Fonts scrambled

Tags: java, vector, graphics, awt

We are currently using the following code to draw texts in the XChart Library, but on the ODROID C2 for example the text is scrambled and not readable (see attached picture for reference). The code used before was the line starting with layout.draw but it was replaced as it was causing issues in the EPS and PDF export. We have a github issue [here](https://github.com/timmolter/XChart/issues/213) which states various reasons for the problems. It is working fine on several other installations.

```
      FontRenderContext frc = g.getFontRenderContext();
      // TextLayout layout = new TextLayout(tickLabel, font, new FontRenderContext(null, true, false));
      TextLayout layout = new TextLayout(tickLabel, getChartPainter().getStyleManager().getAxisTickLabelsFont(), frc);
      Rectangle2D tickLabelBounds = layout.getBounds();
      // layout.draw(g, (float) xOffset, (float) (yOffset + axisTick.getAxis().getPaintZone().getHeight() - tickLocation + tickLabelBounds.getHeight() / 2.0));

      Shape shape = layout.getOutline(null);

      AffineTransform orig = g.getTransform();
      AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
      at.translate((float) xOffset, (float) (yOffset + axisTick.getAxis().getPaintZone().getHeight() - tickLocation + tickLabelBounds.getHeight() / 2.0));
      g.transform(at);
      g.fill(shape);
      g.setTransform(orig);
```

[image: Screenshot showing scrambled fonts]

UPDATE:

Turns out this is arm64 java related. When using 64 Bit Java the issue is as shown, when using 32 Bit Java it is working normally. Still I don't have any idea why or how to fix this.

Comment: Do you use a font which has the characters you want to use?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen We are just using regular labels there (with letters just like this), on the side and bottom it's a scale using normal numbers. As it is working with the layout.draw function I highly assume it is working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was somehow related to oracles arm64 Java running on the odroid c2. After switching to Zulu Java, the issue was resolved.