# Java behaving in a different way on arm64

Tags: java, 64-bit, arm64

I am still working on the issue [Java AWT Fonts scrambled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45785116/java-awt-fonts-scrambled) which I posted here a while ago. More Debugging has been done, and it seems like the arm64 java is the problem. When running 32 bit java on arm64 it is working fine, same on amd64, arm32 and x86.

Is arm64 Java expected to behave different with that code? Shouldn't Java react the same way on every architecture? If yes, where could I open a Bug for that? I am using Oracle Java Runtime Environment if that matters. Java is so complex that I am not sure which is the right place to open that bug so it can get adressed and investigated.

Answer (score 0):

Java is supposed to be platform independent but there are limits when resources of the underlying system need to be used. In that case platform dependency comes into play and you might see different behaviors with different JDKs. Fonts are provided by the operating system so you have some kind of platform specific stuff going on here as well.

Your original question and this one lack some fundamental thing: A workable source that shows the effect on your system. With that it would be possible to try to reproduce your problem on other peoples' systems and might come up with an answer why you have this effect. Your original question e.g. lacks the information what Font you're actually using and I don't see any code where you write the text that appears scrambled.

Comment: The problem is not the font, but the problems are the lines I commented on in this commit: https://github.com/timmolter/XChart/commit/168aedd257c95a48658702e4117aec5ac124ef58

Comment: This PR is the one which breaks it on arm64, before that it is working perfectly fine. The change was necessary because of vector graphics, but now this is causing the issues we are having on arm64.